# Why does opera keep asking me if I want to make it my default browser when it already is?

Tags: browser, opera

Has anyone experienced the same issue?
It is already default and even if I tick "not to show this message again"...it still pops up each time I open a new tab.

UPDATE: I have already made it the default app in system settings. I did it even before that message appeared. So, it is really weird.

Comment: Goto system settings -> details -> Default Applications -> Web and make Opera the default browser in this location.

Comment: @CharlesGreen hey Charles. I did that first thing and the message still appears. It appeared more or less after my update from 15.04 to 15.10

Comment: K - that was the cure when I was trying to use Chrome for a browser, and it asked me the same question continuously.  I later just ticked the box saying 'don't ask me anymore'

Comment: @CharlesGreen done that too. Keep asking each time I open a new tab, even if I tick "dont ask me anymore"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in xdg-settings, a fix has been released. You will just have to wait.

Source: https://forums.opera.com/discussion/1869763/opera-keeps-asking-if-i-want-to-set-it-up-as-default-browser

Comment: Cheers. I'll just wait then.

Comment: opera Version: 40.0.2308.54 - 
    System: Arch Linux (x86_64; KDE)

Still have this problem

Comment: @shigazaru But this website is only for Ubuntu, not Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using ubuntu but having the same issue.

if you are under KDE, I found the solution

[image: KDE File Association]

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one file type not defaulted to Google Chrome.

For Windows 10, go to **Default Apps**

At the bottom of the page click on **Set defaults by app**

Click on **Google Chrome**

Click on **Set this program as default**

Goodbye obnoxious prompt.